# What is p+q? Please give step by step method.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

In this question $p = a\times10^m$ and $q=b\times 10^m$, where $a+b > 10$,

what is $p+q$?

I may be right or wrong, I do not know, but this is what I have so far:

$$p+q > (a+b) \times 10^m$$

Give a step by step method please.

Comment: Wha-ah?  What you might have is $p+q = (a+b) \times 10^m > 10^{m+1}$, but your inequality can't be right.

Comment: @BrianTung yeah that's probably right. Mine was more of a wild attempt than anything, I really was not sure what to do.

Comment: If you change your inequality to an equality then you have what $p+q$ is. (Note however that the question "what is $p+q$" is vague. A question like "what is $p+q$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ would be much clearer)

Comment: Are we given $a, b < 10$?

Comment: @Χpẘ Why should it be an equality? I thought because a + b > 10 that the whole question would use inequalities? Surely if the sum is larger than 10, you can't use equalities because you don't know the exact answer? And yes I agree that would be much clearer, but I found the question on an old exam paper and that was how it was written?

Comment: @LarryB. we're given a + b > 10

Comment: @BenHughes it is an equality because we're just substituting terms. Start with $p+q=p+q$, then substitute for the second $p$ with $p = a\times10^m$ and the second $q$ with $p = b\times10^m$ to get $p+q=a\times10^m+b\times10^m=(a+b)10^m$. Maybe I'm missing something but $a+b>10$ seems irrelevant.

Comment: Do an example. Take $a=b=6$, and $m=2$. What's $600+600$? How does that compare with $(6+6)100$?

Comment: So if the answer is p+q = (a+b)10^m, and a+b > 10, surely p+q > 10x10^m?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly correct to say $p+q=(a+b)\times10^m$, but it will be marked wrong because the unstated assumption is that the thing that isn't a power of $10$ should be between $1$ and $10$.  The expected answer is $p+q=\frac {a+b}{10} \times 10^{m+1}$.  Assuming $1 \le a,b \lt 10$ and as you are given $a+b \gt 10$ you know the thing multiplying the power of $10$ is between $1$ and $10$.